How to decide the correct numbering of aminocyclohexenol?
I'm self studying for a university admission exam. So I'm relying fully on online sources to study, but I often get confused because of differing methods. This is one such case:
According to this entry, after finding the highest priority group, we should number in the direction of the nearest functional group (or bond?) as to give "the first point of difference" the lowest possible locant.
So naturally, looking at this molecule:

I opted to start numbering from the alcohol group, as it is the highest priority group on the molecule, continuing clockwise, granting the amine group the locant '2', as to follow the rule I linked above, numbering the chain when faced with two options in a way that gives the next functional group after the highest priority group the lowest possible number (as the second and third functional groups after the highest priority group represent the first point of difference), and finally finishing at the double bond, giving the two involved carbons the numbers 4 and 5, and since the difference is one, I only have to write the smaller of the two. Giving me:
2-aminocyclohex-4-en-1-ol
But, I was surprised to learn that this is not(?) the correct numbering and naming of this molecule. Sources like PubChem, named this molecule 6-aminocyclohex-3-en-1-ol. Meaning, they've numbered the molecule counter-clockwise, after starting at the highest priority group, alcohol, giving the locant '3' to the first of the carbons involved in the double bond, and '6' to the amine. So at the first point of difference, they did not go with the nearest of the two (lowest locant).

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/12380766
So am I wrong? Where did I go wrong?
Finally, I've asked this question on another forum, and somebody said, in cycloalkenes and cycloalkynes, we immediately number in the direction of the double/triple bond after identifying and starting from the highest priority functional group. Is this a rule that I can always follow?


Speaking of tags, this isn't a heterocycle. As for the nomenclature, pretty much the only source worth referencing is IUPAC Blue Book, which is also freely available. For further details see How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?

Thank you for reviewing my post so quickly! Hopefully I'll get the hang of this community's etiquette soon enough ahaha. I'll refer to the blue book to see if I can find an answer there, which I, again, thanks to you, learned there's a free copy of, because just a minute ago I clicked on a link from an answer to another post, and it lead to a 175$ version.
... Sorry about the wrong tag too lol! have a good day!
